# Passing vector pointer in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector pointer which pointed to a vector of array. I tried to set each element in 
vector of array in below.

```
vector array
index: vector[0] vector[1] vector[2] vector[3] vector[4]
value:  0        1         2         3         4
```

> error: request for member 'push_back' in 'input-> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator](((long unsigned int)k))', which is of non-class type 'int'

The source code are as follows,it gets the error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
void insert( vector<int> *input)    
{
  for(int k=0; k<5; k++)
  {
    (*input)[k].push_back(k);
  }
  return;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int>* ivec = new vector<int>[5];
   insert(ivec);
   vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec[0].begin();

   for(int ix = 0; iter != ivec[0].end(); ++iter, ++ix)
   {
     cout << *iter << endl;
   }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: side note: you need to delete somewhere variable allocated with new

Comment: What is the point of this? Can't you just use a vector of vectors?

Comment: I think you just want `input[k].push_back(k);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compiles:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void insert( vector<int> *input)
{
  for(int k=0; k<5; k++)
  {
    input[k].push_back(k); // <== MODIFIED
  }
  return;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int>* ivec = new vector<int>[5];
   insert(ivec);
   vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec[0].begin();

   for(int ix = 0; iter != ivec[0].end(); ++iter, ++ix)
   {
     cout << *iter << endl;
   }

    return 0;
 }
```

What's wrong?

- `(*vector)` is of type vector...
- `(*vector)[k]` applies operator[] of the type vector, resultin in an int... which does not have a push_back method

## A vector of vector approach

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void insert( vector<vector<int> > &input)
{
  int k=0;
  vector<vector<int> >::iterator it=input.begin();
  for(;it!=input.end();++it,++k)
  {
    it->push_back(k);
  }
  return;
}

int main()
{
   vector<vector<int> > ivec=vector<vector<int> >(5);
   insert(ivec);
   vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec[0].begin();

   for(int ix = 0; iter != ivec[0].end(); ++iter, ++ix)
   {
     cout << *iter << endl;
   }

    return 0;
 }
```